# Css style not working well when resizing chart height in angular application

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap, chart.js, angular-chart

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eBfVMi87ctmSOxEWkctI?p=preview). I have passing json object to chart, i want to give `width 100%` to line chart and height to 100px, but when we minimizing height css does not work expected. The chart does not take height and width of its parent div/panel.

Answer (score 2):

Use custom `CSS` to specify the dimensions:

**CSS:**

```
.panel{width:100%;height:300px;}
.panel-body{width:100%;height:270px;}
.chart-container{height:100%!important;}
canvas{width:100%;height:100%!important;}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/gVRwrEKWA9HaTCWgbyIS?p=preview

When a window is resized, the canvas and the graph gets new dimension as inline style which overrides the css rules in the stylesheets. To prevent this override, use `!important`

Comment: Hi KK, I tried it and it work well when height is same as you provided, actually i want height 100 px to chart, but once i update it to 100 px then css is not works on it.

Comment: Hi @KK , can you look at the mouse hour on data points where you find tooltip, the tooltip does not render properly. That is  the problem, when we minimize size we cannot find point, cannot read message given by tooltip.

Comment: @PramodGaikwad I think that's expected behavior because when you alter the aspect ratio of the canvas, the elements which depends on the dimension of canvas will be affected too. If you further customize it, then it may have some other issues

Comment: I want that graph should have height around 300px and width of 100% of the page. So is there any other way apart from canvas using which I can do it? Also please suggest me if there is any other better library than current one. I am using Chart.js.

Comment: @PramodGaikwad I think you can continue using the chart.js library. Check if there is feature to trigger resize on chart. You can trigger resize on chart which might fix the tooltip dimensions.

Comment: @K K : Thanks for your help, finally we manage to resize chart.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have to manage to resize chart by adding one more global variable in chart.js and assigning its value from our controller where we defined our chart.
In chart.js we can assign our new height as:

```
 canvas.height = this.chart.height = Chart.defaults.global.defaultHeight; // newHeight;
```

In our controller we can change/update it as:

```
 Chart.defaults.global.defaultHeight = 250;
```

I did not know any other way which will be better, any other suggestion will be appreciated.